# What word would work as a better substitute for "Stalker"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, attributive-nouns, compound-adjectives

## Context

I am working on a game and one of the Classes in it is "Rogue". (Original, I know.) I'm trying to find a term that accurately describes and can serve as a name for one of the Subclasses. (Preferably a single-word term, if possible.)

## Needs

The term ideally needs to describe somebody who excels at 1) following a target, 2) breaking into locations, and 3) collecting information without being caught. It should ideally be able to work as an adjective if at all possible, but an attributive noun could work (with some leniency for other nouns, but if possible, please avoid as such), potentially; however, the term should **not** imply an occupational aspect to the behaviour (such as "Spy" or "Investigator"). It shouldn't be inherently a very negative term either, as is the case with "stalker" or "prowler". It shouldn't imply theft such as with "thief", "burglar", or "robber". I'd prefer one word, but a two-word option could work as well, but please, nothing larger than that.

## My Effort

Due to personal reasons, my first thought was "Stalker", but that word conveys too heavy of a connotation. My second thought was "Lurker", but it had a similar issue, alongside the fact it doesn't imply most of the conditions. I tried "Trespasser" but that feels too heavy on the Breaking & Entering side with little implication of following a target.
"Scout" doesn't work because it is too generalized (ignoring occupational implications, of course).

## Conclusion

I know I am asking for a tough answer. If you can help me, I'd appreciate it. I'm still trying on my own to find a good word, but if anyone can suggest something that helps, I'd be so grateful! I know this comes across as super picky, but I tried to be specific so not to waste anyone's time. Please and thank you!

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that a person in the police or private detective business who follows someone around is a "tail".

Comment: Wouldn't work due to 1) professional implication and 2) it implies only the "following" aspect. That said, thank you still.

Comment: There probably are some other terms that are used in detective novels, but I don't read those much.

Comment: You have a lot of criteria for the word you want. So many constraints may exclude any possible candidate word. Your description sounded like 'spy' to me, but you dismiss that as an occupation. I think that means you want this as an optional attribute rather than an essential part. However, if this is a class of person (and the person can't be of another class _and_ must be of some class) then 'spy' would be fine.  I mean don't spies have day jobs as their cover?

Comment: Super picky is actually a good thing when you're asking here. The narrower you can make your criteria, the better, so that your question actually has a chance of having a "correct" answer rather than just a lot of ideas or suggestions. So thanks for that.

Comment: Dismissed as an occupation, for this, is mandatory, or rather to say, it can't outright suggest an occupational reason. I have a specific system design in mind is why. It's not that it can't work as an occupation, such as the suggested "Exfiltrator", but it shouldn't make someone think, "Oh! This person is a stalker because it's their job." Occupations make the needed term too benign-seeming whereas the issue with "stalker" is it sounds too malicious. I want something more neutral with maybe a minor slant in one way or the other. In short, on a scale of 1-100, it should be between 40-60.

Comment: You might consider words in the vein of “private eye”, as they excel at — are professionally employed for — precisely the skills you describe. There is a wealth of options in this constellation, ranging from “gumshoe” to “dick”. You can use words from other languages for the same function. You can use eponyms for famous PIs like “Archie”.

Comment: I have received 2 downvotes on this yesterday. Could the downvoters please explain why? This question is not off-topic, gives sufficient detail to prevent being overly-broad, and is not too narrow as to be unanswerable as made evident by Jason Bassford's answer being given almost immediately and being exactly what I was looking for in every respect. If there was something this question could improve on without changing the spirit of the question or invalidating good answers, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible word is [**shadow**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shadow), which can be used as a noun, verb, or adjective, and which has many different senses. Overall, it has a neutral meaning, and, even though it can be, it's not inherently associated with a profession or seen as something negative.

Comment: This is like a nicer version of 'stalker'.

Comment: Ooh... I like this. Shadow gives a bunch of implications, can suggest following, discreet information-gathering, and the ability to access locations you normally couldn't access. I want to see what other people suggest, but between this and Hellion's answer, I may be stuck picking from one of these two. I like both of your suggestions as they both work! I'm kind of leaning towards yours though now that I read it! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a few possibilities for you:

- **espionage artist:** does everything a spy can do, but isn't a spy by trade.
- **reconnaissance artist:** a person skilled in techniques of observational information-gathering.
- **information exfiltrator:** specializes in locating and extracting critical data from hostile locations.

Comment: I may be able to make use of "Exfiltrator". I'd like to hear other thoughts though. This word on paper is a perfect match, but it's not common enough that I think people would understand it right away; however, there's a reason I didn't mark "It must be a common term," as a criteria. If other answers don't work better, I may select this as my answer. The only problem is it lacks the implication of following someone. Still, a strong answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your request for an adjective leads me to

> **stealthy**, *adjective*
>   \ˈstel-thē  \
>   stealthier; stealthiest
>   1 : slow, deliberate, and secret in action or character
>   2a : intended to escape observation : FURTIVE
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stealthy</sup>

If you were looking for a noun, you could go a little more occupational with **covert operative**, though that sounds governmenty and formal.

Comment: Stealthy works to describe part of the type, but doesn't seem to imply the B&E portion. That said, I am not opposed to it. I will edit my OP to allow for a little more flexibility in regards to nouns, but covert operative won't work as it needs to exclude outright jobs for what I'm going for, as the OP mentioned.